# Mysql stock calculation query

Tags: mysql

I have below table data

```
Product Reason Qty
Pepsi   IN     10
Pepsi   Out    2
Pepsi   In     15
Pepsi   Out    5 
Coke    IN     100
Coke    Out    20
Coke    In     35
Coke    Out    25
Fanta   Out     55
```

and I want to get result like below:

```
Product Qty
Pepsi   18
Coke    90
Fanta   -55
```

I have written below query but I am not getting Fanta in output.

```
select indata.Name,indata.PRODUCTS_ID, (indata.QTY - outdata.QTY) as `QTY` from
(
(select 
    distinct
    stock.PRODUCTS_ID,
    stock.Name,
    stock.QTY
    from stock where reason in ('IN','REFUND') 
    ) indata,
(select 
    distinct
    stock.PRODUCTS_ID,
    stock.Name,
    stock.QTY
    from stock where reason in ('OUT','WASTE') 
) outdata
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a good candidate for conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Product,
       SUM(CASE WHEN reason IN ('IN','REFUND') THEN Qty 
                WHEN reason IN ('OUT','WASTE') THEN -Qty
                ELSE NULL END) AS Qty
FROM stock
GROUP BY Product;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/CZVM76552)**</kbd>